# Transpose rows to columns and then group by unique ID values

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I'm looking for a way to dynamically transpose row variables and their values into columns and then group them by their unique original row ID's in R. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Current table:

| ID | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | process | assessment |
| 111 | account number | 7583901264 |
| 111 | surname | James |
| 222 | policy number | P761 |
| 222 | process | review |
| 222 | account number | 4720129840 |
| 333 | claim value | $1000.00 |
| 333 | claim date | 2021-11-12 09:00:00 |

Desired table:

| ID | process | account number | surname | policy number | claim value | claim date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | assessment | 7583901264 | James |  |  |  |
| 222 | review | 4720129840 |  | P761 |  |  |
| 333 |  |  |  |  | $1000.00 | 2021-11-12 09:00:00 |

Keep in mind that not all unique ID's in my original table have the same number of rows and the same type of variables

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample of data - `dput()` is the nicest way to do this because it is copy/pasteable.

Comment: I've added some tables. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              names_from = Variable,
              values_from = Value)


# A tibble: 3 x 7
     ID process    `account number` surname `policy number` `claim value` `claim date`  
  <int> <chr>      <chr>            <chr>   <chr>           <chr>         <chr>         
1   111 assessment 7583901264       James   NA              NA            NA            
2   222 review     4720129840       NA      P761            NA            NA            
3   333 NA         NA               NA      NA              $1000.00      12.11.2021 9:~
```

or

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data = setDT(df), formula = ID ~ Variable, value.var = "Value")

    ID account number      claim date claim value policy number    process surname
1: 111     7583901264            <NA>        <NA>          <NA> assessment   James
2: 222     4720129840            <NA>        <NA>          P761     review    <NA>
3: 333           <NA> 12.11.2021 9:00    $1000.00          <NA>       <NA>    <NA>
```

then do the data type conversion

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For the dcast solution, I end up with either 0 or 1 as values in my cells?

Comment: updated. try specifying `value.var`